# raise TypeError when using the scipy.optimize library in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize

Hi all I am using the from scipy.optimize import leastsq library to the least squares regression, however I am getting the error:

```
    raise TypeError(f"Improper input: func input vector length N={n} must"
TypeError: Improper input: func input vector length N=7 must not exceed func output vector length M=6
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, below is my code

```
def resfun(In,A_pts,B_pts):

    Trans_A_pt=trans(In,A_pts)

    Res=sqrt(square((Trans_A_pt[:,0]-B_pts[:,0]))+square((Trans_A_pt[:,1]-B_pts[:,1]))+square((Trans_A_pt[:,2]-B_pts[:,2])))

    return Res

WL=array([
    [100.172646,202.0848081,1.243437],[100.327606,202.342361,1.254414],[100.239075,202.370438,0.847693],
    [100.239075,202.370438,0.847693],[100.306305,202.202209,1.074094],[100.202568,202.223648,1.076712]])


NT=array([
    [100.024971,202.205734,1.32802],[100.14994,202.508713,1.32],[100.045151,202.504639,0.86579],
    [100.147476,202.190872,0.87439],[100.149559,202.341949,1.1281],[100.032089,202.350433,1.13098]])

res_lsq=leastsq(resfun,[1,0,0,0,0,0,0],args=(WL,NT))
```

Comment: What don't you understand?  The `leastsq` documented requirements for the `resfun` function (input and output length)?  or why your function doesn't meet that requirement?  The initial guess has 7 elements.  What does `resfun` return?

Comment: The resfun returns the residual vector, between all my points. I don't quite understand why that error is showing up when I am running my code

Comment: What you call `res` or think it is, doesn't matter.  What matters to `leastsq` is its `shape` compared to the shape of `In`.  The error says `res` is too short.  `In`, derived from the initial guess is (7,).  I don't know what `res` is (`trans` is unknown), but its shape may have something to do with the dimensions of `WL`.  REREAD THE DOCS.

Comment: Okay I understood the problem, thanks!